# Verifying that generic type argument conforms to 2 unrelated types

Tags: scala, generics, variance, type-bounds

In Scala one can specify type bound for generic argument.

For example, to ensure that `A` will conform `SomeType1` one can do:

```
trait Example[A <: SomeType1]
```

Now, lets say I need to make sure that `A` conforms to 2 unrelated types `SomeType1` and `SomeType2`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a product type, in Scala you can express such things with `with`, i.e:

```
trait Example[A <: SomeType1 with SomeType2]
```